# Add htmlAttributes globally to EditorFor in MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to disable the HTML id's in forms because I'm using multiple Ajax forms on one page.
I'm currently doing it like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AccountNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id="" } })
```

But I feel there has to be a way to declare it globally, like in a custom view engine configuration. I don't like doing it on every editor, and I don't like making a editortemplate for every data type like [UkadcHtmlAttributeProvider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UkadcHtmlAttributeProvider) does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a custom extension method wrapping the native one:

```
public static class MyHtmlExtensions 
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MyEditorFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)        
    {
        return html.EditorFor(expression, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id=""}});
    }
}
```

Then, in your view:

```
@Html.MyEditorFor(model => model.AccountNumber);
```

Comment: Thanks, going to try that. Tried to make a custom EditorFor, but didn't try wrapping the existing one.